# GEdit - Plugin to find and open a partial under cursor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gedit

GMate contains a plugin to extract portion of code into a partial. But is there anything to do the opposite, IE, to find a partial on disk and automatically open it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the external tool 'jump' for it.
[You will find it on github](https://github.com/antifarben/kaese-und-toast-gedit/blob/master/gedit/tools/jump)